# C# , UWP (TextBlock , Binding)

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I limit the number of characters in this TextBlock?
E.g.: It can only show up to 5 characters.

```xaml
<TextBlock >
    <Run Text="Tender Amount:"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding TenderAmount, 
                Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, 
                ConverterParameter='{}{0:C}'}" />
</TextBlock>
```

btw heres the Code in my Converter

```
public sealed class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (parameter == null)
            return value;

        return string.Format((string)parameter, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: I'd recommend using a `TextBox` instead of a `TextBlock` and then looking for `TextChanged` event.

Comment: Any effort from your end? I would start by restricting the `TenderAmount` to 99999, if it is numeric

Comment: i prefer TextBlock , @bit yes , like that. i want to set the MaxValue of TenderAmount to = 100000 or 6 digits

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own *Binding Converter* to limit the number of displayed characters.

This one for example would simply limit the number of displayed characters to the first 5 characters in the string (or string representation of whatever you are passing into it).

```
public class StringLengthLimitConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string val = value.ToString();
        int length = parameter as int? ?? 5;
        if (val.Length > length)
            return val.Substring(0, length);
        return val;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```xaml
<Run Text="{Binding Path=TenderAmount, 
               Converter={StaticResource StringLengthLimitConverter},
               ConverterParameter=5}" />
```

Depending on what you actually want to do, you might want to add an ellipsis (`…`) at the end.

Comment: hello , thanks for your suggestion , I edited my question , how can i implement your method in my converter , thanks.

Comment: @NicoTing I just saw you comment on your question, that you want to limit the number itself. If the number is for example `123456789` do you want it to show up as `12345`, `56789` or `99999`? If the number is less than 5 characters long (e.g. 123) should it show up as `00123` or `123`?

Comment: no , just MaxLength , and the user can only just tender 999999.99 , if he taps/clicks another button , it will just stays with 999999.99

Comment: @NicoTing I have **no** idea what you mean by that. What do you mean with "the user can only just tender 999999.99"? Please provide some examples of what `TenderAmount` is and what the displayed text should be in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own converter like:

```
public class StringMaxLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        int MaxLength = Convert.ToInt32(parameter);
        string TheString = (string)Value;

        if (MaxLength > TheString.Length)
        {
            return TheString.SubString(0, MaxLength);
        }
        else
        {
            return TheString;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Declare it in your resources like:

```xaml
<local:StringMaxLengthConverter x:Key="StrMaxLengthCvtr"/>
```

Use it in your TextBlock and pass the max string length like:

```xaml
<TextBlock >
  <Run Text="Tender Amount:"/>
  <Run Text="{Binding TenderAmount, Converter={StaticResource StrMaxLengthCvtr}, ConverterParameter=5}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks , hello i tried your example , but why im having error with the 'Convert'? it says it is a method.